# While loop filter categories

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I have a very basic setup: A table called "elements" and which has columns "positive","negative","type" and I need to select all the elements and loop only through the ones that have a type of "video". Here's what I have now:

```
require_once 'dbcon.php';

    $stmt = $db->prepare("select positive, negative,type from elements");
    $stmt->bind_result($pos,$neg$type);
    $stmt->execute();

    while($stmt->fetch()){
        echo $type
    }
```

I've tried with a `if($type=='video')` and `while(($stmt->fetch()) && ( $type=='video ))` , but I don't get any results back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to apply `WHERE` in query itself:

```
SELECT `positive`, `negative`, `type` FROM `elements` WHERE `type`='video'
```

Comment: Yeah I had that working for me, but is that a proper way of doing it? that way I need to do a db query for each category. Also excuse me but I'm just learning php.

Comment: It is a best way to resolve problem that you've described. If you have other conditions with other needed columns values - then you should decide what to do. (at least, that should be described in question)

Comment: No it's just these values I need.

Comment: If it is a set of values, then use `IN` operator.